# SQL person duplicates

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

How can I eliminate the duplicates of the persons.

```
SELECT Persons.Id, Activity.Activity, Activity.Description, Activity.StartDate, Activity.EndDate
FROM Activity
INNER JOIN Login_Activity ON Activity.ActivityId = Login_Activity.ActivityId
INNER JOIN Persons ON Login_Activity.LoginId = Persons.LoginId
AND Activity.Description IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Persons.Id DESC


Person 1 - Activity 1
Person 1 - Activity 2
Person 2 - Activity 1
Person 3 - Activity 2
Person 3 - Activity 3
```

EDIT: I want this result.

```
Person 1 - Activity 1
Person 2 - Activity 1
Person 3 - Activity 3
```

It's beacuse the Activity tables also contains som timestables and I only want the last datetime for every activity. For that problem I just use the ORDER DESC function. But I also need to eliminate the duplicates.

EDIT2: If I just use the SQL query to sort the max value and then use PHP array to only show the persons once.

```
mainArray = array(

 'person' => '1', 'Activity' => 'abc', 

'person' => '1', 'Activity' => 'cba',

'person' => '2', 'Activity' => 'abc',

'person' => '2', 'Activity' => 'cba',

'person' => '3', 'Activity' => 'cba'

);
```

Comment: What result do you want. There are many possibilities where each person only appears once.

Comment: How do you determine which activity to show on person? Because you say `I just use the ORDER DESC`, but on the given example `I want this result` you have put `Activity 1` where there are possible `1 or 2`.

Comment: one or more persons doesn't have all the activity's. the persons who have more than one Activity I want to show the activity with the last date. Persons must not be duplicated but 2 persons may have the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate subquery that will identify the most recent (or whatever) login activity that you want for each user.  Assuming `Login_Activity` has a field called `LoginActivityID` which is an integer auto-increment field, then this would work:

```
SELECT
    P.Id, 
    A.Activity, 
    A.Description, 
    A.StartDate, 
    A.EndDate
FROM
    Persons P
            INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  LA2.LoginId, MAX(LA2.LoginActivityID) LoginActivityID
        FROM    Login_Activity LA2
                        INNER JOIN
                Activity A2
        WHERE   A2.Description IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY LA2.LoginId
    ) LAX
            ON
        P.LoginId = LAX.LoginId
            INNER JOIN
    Login_Activity LA
            ON
        LAX.LoginActivityID = LA.LoginActivityID
            INNER JOIN
    Activity A
            ON
        LA.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the GROUP BY function on the PersonId column in the Persons table?

Comment: @StefanFrederiksen, if you just wanted the max value along with the person, then yes, but since you want to show a bunch of data related to the max, then you want to do it in a subquery.

Comment: I think I only need the max value with the person. Look at my edit.

Comment: A solution like this with a correlated sub-query can work, but it is slow.

Comment: @dbenham, actually, that's not a correlated subquery.  It's using a subquery as a table that's joined.  Performance is usually pretty good.

Comment: Oops - sorry, you are correct. It isn't correlated. Never-the-less, it likely must read from Activity and Login_Activity in two steps. It is generic such that any SQL engine should support it, but most databases have better options.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what SQL flavor you are using - it makes a big difference as to what is possible.

Most databases support the RANK function nowadays, which provides a very efficient solution. (One notable exception is MySql - it does not support RANK)

Within the CTE, RANK() is used to rank all the activities for each person in descending date order. I assume you want to keep the latest one to be completed, and in the event of a tie, the latest one to start, and if still a tie, I use the activity PK as a tie breaker to make the query determinate.

The outer query simply selects all records from the CTE that have a rank of 1.

This is able to provide the answer with a single scan of the Activity table - no nasty correlated sub-query to slow things down :-)

```
with rankedActivities as (
 select p.Id,
        a.Activity,
        a.Description,
        a.StartDate,
        a.EndDate
        Rank() over (
          partition by p.Id
          order by a.EndDate desc, a.StartDate desc, a.ActivityId desc
        ) dateRank
   from persons p
   inner join Login_Activity la
      on la.LoginId = p.LoginId
   inner join Activity a
      on a.ActivityId = la.ActivityId
)
select Id,
       Activity,
       Description,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
  from rankedActivies
 where dateRank=1
;
```